# I want to access the whole row of datagrid using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

The steps to get that rows in javascript as follows:
how to Handle the RowDataBound event of the Grid?

how to Bind the ID OF EACH RECORD in checkbox attribute?

That’s all.
Pls,help me to come out.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to handle ID in checkbox.
1. Multiple checkbox with the same 'name' attribute are handled over Form as comma separated value. So client side:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" value="2"/>
...
```

On server side looks like:

```
Request.Form["a1"]="1,2"
```

The second solution - place hidden field for each row with ID of row, so you could locate at jscript this hidden from row:

```
$get("myHidden", myRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle the RowDataBound event to do this.  Use a [CheckboxField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx)...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="FIELD_NAME_HERE" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```